# convolution and groupdelay

Tags: matlab

I have been given a sinusoidal signal `x` in time domain,asked to investigate the frequncy responce of the signal using matlab and observing the result,and using `grpdelay(x,1)` command in matlab to observe the group delay of the signal .and taking `y=conv(x,x);`which define the convolution of `x` signal by itself and then asked to use the `grpdelay(y,1)`.
My question here is what change should I exspect to see in group delay figure of `conv(x,x)`?
or better to say how convolving of the signal by itself would effect the group delay of the signal.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion here. Frequency Response and Group Delay are properties of a System not the properties of a signal. You can only calculate the spectrum of a signal (magnitude and phase). A "signal" doesn't have group delay unless it's the impulse response of an LTI system.

Comment: But you could view any signal as the impulse response of an LTI system. I think the question is valid.